# Visual Studio 2010 hangs up when opening a .sql file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I launch VS 2010, and simply open any ordinary (or blank) .sql file and it shows up incorrectly drawn inside the IDE.  It draws the document tab, but nothing else.  If I type on the keyboard, VS locks up.  This only appears to be a problem with files that have the extension ".sql" and has no bearing on the actual content. I also noticed that in the Solution Explorer, those .sql files show the icon that is the same one associated with .js files.

Comment: Do you have any of 2010 power toys installed?

Comment: Is the file large?  Does this same behavior occur on an empty file with a .sql extension?  If so, it appears that there is some corruption and a reinstall of VS might be your best bet.

Comment: I have seen this happen some times, the whole screen looks black but I can still select text. Are you running the latest Azure SDK? Have you tried running VS in Safe mode to see if it is plugin related?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Problem solved. I was able to resolve the problem by running the `DACProjectSystemSetup_enu.msi` installer found on the [**VS2010-SP1 ISO**](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=210710) under the root directory. You *might* also need to re-install `DACFramework_enu.msi` and `TSqlLanguageService_enu.msi`.

I believe the problem was created as a result of installing SQL Server 2008 R2 after installing VS2010.

Comment: Thankyou so much, this has been bugging me for ages!

Comment: Thanks a bundle :)  For me, the minimum set of those MSIs that I needed to install was DACProjectSystemSetup_enu.msi and TSqlLanguageService_enu.msi

Comment: I also found I had to re-install the SharedManagementObjects MSIs from the WCU\SMO folder.  Without that, I would get missing assembly errors plus generally strange behavior when trying to save a SQL file.

Comment: THANK YOU. I wish I could +10 you.

Comment: Note if you have SP1 you have to install from the VS 2010 SP1 DVD, not from the original install DVD.  The appropriate packages are under the root folder instead of a subfolder.

Comment: I was having this problem after uninstalling SQL Server 2008 R2 and then installing SQL Server 2012. I had to install all three packages.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This was crippling me. Like others, I had to install all three.

Comment: Thank you for this. For what it's worth, I needed all three of the above

Comment: For me,  I this might have been related to UNinstalling SQL 2008, but I can't be 100% sure. Big thanks from me too.

Comment: I too had to download 2/3 above (just do all 3 to be safe) to read .sql files BUT I also had to download the SharedManagementObjects msi to save files without errors about missing dll's (thanks Cheetah!)...I found that here:http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=16978

Comment: This is a useful answer

Comment: Your link to answer is not available anymore!

Comment: @BobSort, thanks for the heads up, I simplified my answer to the bare essentials.

Answer (score 9):

I was able to fix the issue by:

1. Downloading the SP1 DVD ISO from [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=210710).
2. Executing `DACProjectSystemSetup_enu.msi` from the root of the ISO.

These 2 simple steps resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and Install below MSIs from VS 2010 Setup folder:

- DACFramework_enu.msi
- DACProjectSystemSetup_enu.msi
- TSqlLanguageService_enu.msi

Answer (score 0):

microsoft.visualstudio.editor.implementation clr20r3
I got mine working with the following steps

1. Navigate to
   C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\
2. Rename ComponentModelCache directory to 1ComponentModelCache1 and
   the folder will be recreated later
3. Retry