# Error while trying to create a new SQL Server 2008 database project

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010

I receive the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser, Version=10.0.0.0... The system cannot find the file specified.

Reading the following [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/3e7a2800-2547-40bb-b7bd-cca6bc71aea0) I made a repair to SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) Class Library but no success there.

Answer (score 2):

As referenced in this post, did you reinstall these three components?

Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types - [LINK](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=123721&clcid=0x409)

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Objects - [LINK](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=123708&clcid=0x409)

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client - [LINK](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=123717&clcid=0x409)

[original post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/5abfbb57-dac9-4039-b121-ae21c9b9352c)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. But I don't know how :). The solution to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526906/visual-studio-2010-hangs-up-when-opening-a-sql-file) problem might be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error, followed this procedure, and it worked for me.

http://blog.anthonybaker.me/2011/02/cannot-load-file-or-assembly.html

(Although my installers where not in the WCU folder, but at the root of the image...)