# Visual Studio 2008 hangs when beginning to edit SQL file in Database Project

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have a database project that keeps track of all my scripts and stored procedures. This project is the project type you get when you create a new project, then select Other Project Types, then database project. So there are a ton of .sql files (2000+) in the project - is that what's causing my performance issues?

When I start editing a .sql file in this project, it does my first edit (like deletes a character or something), but then VS hangs for like 10-12 seconds, and I just have to wait until it's done doing whatever it does, then I can continue editing. Then, when I press Ctrl+S, it takes another 10 or 12 seconds to save the file. Considering I press Ctrl+S about every 10 seconds, this takes up a lot of time, not to mention it's extremely frustrating!

Has anyone else experienced this? Do you have any tips on how to make editing .sql files within a VS database project perform better?

Comment: I doubt it is related to sql/db project types. I get the same in a large cpp project. No idea what it is though, its quite annoying. I did wonder if it is related to a version control plug in.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526906/visual-studio-2010-hangs-up-when-opening-a-sql-file