# Visual Studio 2010 crashes on opening! I'm starting to hate everything!

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Howdy, I noticed that Visual Studio crashed when I tried to open a .SQL file. Perhaps this was due to me installing SQL SERVER 2008 last week. Anyway to overcome the issue I repaired Visual Studio using the install disc. One hour later and a couple of reboots the issue remained. However now the thing crashes as soon as I select a project!

Here's what the event viewer says:

> EventType clr20r3, P1 devenv.exe, P2
>   10.0.40219.1, P3 4d5f2a73, P4 microsoft.visualstudio.editor.implementation,
>   P5 10.0.0.0, P6 4d5f2b24, P7 d2, P8
>   9a, P9 system.nullreferenceexception,
>   P10 NIL.

I'm starting to lose the will to live.

With Regards to Andrei Drynov's answer / comment **

Okay, the service pack is on there, the contents of the SQL file are irrelevant as the files opened with ease previously and it happens on that file type not a specific file also the crashing happens regardless of the project/solution I select? I do agree that I am being dramatic!

After starting in safe mode **

I got the following error

> "An exception was encountered while
>   constructing the content of this
>   frame.  This information is also
>   logged by running the application with
>   the /log parameter on the command
>   line, which stores results in
>   "C:\Documents and
>   Settings\XXXXXXX\Application
>   Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ActivityLog.xml".
>
> Exception details:
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException:
>   Package
>   'Attrice.TeamFoundation.Sidekicks.VisualStudio.MainPackage,
>   Attrice.TeamFoundation.Sidekicks.Package.10,
>   Version=3.0.3.1, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=14bece0700b6dc89'
>   failed to load.    at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
>   errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)    at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32
>   errorCode)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.GetPackage()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()

I then got the following

> Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> 'C:\Dev\XXXXXX.Deploy.wdproj'
>   cannot be opened because its project
>   type (.wdproj) is not supported by
>   this version of the application.
>
> To open it, please use a version that
>   supports this type of project.

So I'll reinstall the Visual Studio® 2010 Web Deployment Projects to see if that works? How odd.

Comment: The log mentions Team Foundation Sidekicks installed. Could it be corrupt? You need correct version 3.0 for Visual Studio 2010. Try re-installing it.For web deployment projects check http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=89f2c4f5-5d3a-49b6-bcad-f776c6edfa63.  If you have a web deployment project in the solution, remove it and check. Is it version 2008?

Comment: I've uninstalled TF Sidekicks -  the application doesn't show/display .SQL files and when I try to open one it crashes. Downer.

Comment: Mike, judging by the exception description, Sidekicks is the culprit. Ignore web deployment project for a while. Can you install Sidekicks 3.0 again, create a vanilla project similar to yours and add those SQL files to it, then open the solution again to see if VS2010 crashes or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This worked a treat!

Thank God!

[Visual Studio 2010 hangs up when opening a .sql file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526906/visual-studio-2010-hangs-up-when-opening-a-sql-file)

Comment: Hopefully you figured it out before you actually hated everything.

Answer (score 0):

You are being quite dramatic )))

Please provide more information, e.g. post the SQL file contents, tell more about the project type, etc.

BTW, did you install service pack 1?

Answer (score 0):

I had a VS2010 solution with two Database projects that, on and off, crashed VS2010 on opening.

After a few attempts I noticed that the .SLN file had the two projects correctly referenced BUT the TAG SccNumberOfProjects referenced `3` instead of `2`.

```
Global\GlobalSection\SccNumberOfProjects = 3
```

I "text-edited" for 2 and it worked, at least for now.

As the crash was happening on and off with no apparent reason, **I cannot guarantee that this was in fact THE solution; use at your own risk and of course, backup files first.** ;)