# Visual Studio 2010 does not open .sql file

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have somewhat similar issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526906/visual-studio-2010-hangs-up-when-opening-a-sql-file) my VS 2010 does not hangup anymore after installing below three as suggested but it does not open .sql either - it says Error - TF10187 could not open C:.sql

```
DACFramework_enu.msi,
DACProjectSystemSetup_enu.msi,
TSqlLanguageService_enu.msi
```

any clue how to solve this? my last resort will be try to install VS 2010 again :(
    thanks,

Comment: did you have a question, or are you just venting?

Comment: question on how to solve this...updated post. THanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to re-install SQL Server 2008 and things started working. Looks like SQL Server should be installed after VS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

TF10187 is a TFS error. The solution is to:

1. Get latest version
2. Check both of the overwrite checkboxes
3. Click "Get"