# Visual Studio 2012 Crashs whenever I try to open any project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Last night I ran my program running simulations. I woke up this morning the program had been terminated (it wasn't supposed to), the debug folder was deleted, and visual studio had restarted. Now whenever I try to open any project in visual studio it crashes. What could have happened? I'm completely stumped. Here is some information if anyone can make sense of this:

```
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: devenv.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 11.0.50727.1
  Problem Signature 03: 5011ecaa
  Problem Signature 04: System.ComponentModel.Composition
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.30319.18060
  Problem Signature 06: 51ee085b
  Problem Signature 07: 16c
  Problem Signature 08: 4f
  Problem Signature 09: JT1X0453KJCJF34Q1KKIEV0ZVYPHQ53A
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Comment: Have a look at [Visual Studio 2012 crashes everytime I try to debug with error CLR20r3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189625/visual-studio-2012-crashes-everytime-i-try-to-debug-with-error-clr20r3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably an extension you installed is crashing. Try starting VS in safe mode and disabling one by one...

Comment: It was the web developers extension included by default with VS 2012 install. to delete I entered the following into the cmdline:

MSiExec.exe /X{B96FCD4F-6EDD-4258-8A6D-0FCEA8445E3E}